# Metadatafile couldnt be found

Tags: c#, powershell, xaml

I am currently working on an interface in C# which is powered by a Powershellscript. I wanted to include a class which i wrote with custom namespaces in it. If i want to include the class it tells me that it couldnt find the Metadata file of my dll. [The error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr1Ki.png) [The class + Add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQjGl.png)

I already tried to load the dll with LoadFrom and also load all other dlls it need but there is always the same problem

Comment: Make sure the path is correct.  The dll cannot be found due to the pathname.

Comment: Its the right path

Comment: Make sure the dll is in folder and the permission are correct on the folder.  The error says "FILE Could not be found".  You may not be running Powershell as Admin so in windows the file is there, but in PS it doesn't have permission to access file.

Comment: Thank you that worked i had to run it as Admin